# Python: Program Outputs Different Values Every Time It Runs

Tags: python, matrix, output

This problem has been occurring for a couple months now with any project that uses complicated sets of equations (such as for composite mechanics analysis or thrust/fluid flow analysis). Simple calculations, iterative methods, and Numpy matrices seem to work fine on their own though. And just to be sure, I have tried completely uninstalling and reinstalling Python and Pycharm, but the same problem persists.

For the past couple months, any code that incorporates more complex mathematics, such as those described above, will output different values despite all input values and calculations being constant. The different codes have no means of variation or randomness. I've noticed these incorrect outputs usually occur within arrays/matrices, and I can tell the output values are incorrect because the expected numbers are instead absurdly large.

For example, an element within a matrix is expected to be 5.197e+7, but instead, the code outputs 3.322e+257 for that same element. However, upon running the code a second time, the code produces an output of 2.822e+204 for the exact same element. Only upon the third run does the code output the correct value for that element, which is 5.197e+7. This process can take anywhere from 1 to 15  separate runs for the same, unchanging code in order to output the correct value.

Another interesting aspect is that the calculations I am coding usually require multiple iterations of said code. However, even though I am resetting the arrays that temporarily save all values (other than final values that no longer affect the calculations), whatever is causing these "errors is being carried through the code until the end of the iterations. To my understanding, this shouldn't be the case since, at the end of an iteration, the code is setting all values, other than the known initial values, to 0 and recalculating. This would mean that the code is continuously making the same error.

Below are some examples of the program's expected output vs actual outputs.

**Expected Output for First Iteration**

```
NM = [[ 2.57939977e+04]
 [ 3.03926820e+04]
 [-3.55271368e-13]
 [ 1.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.00000000e+00]
 [ 2.60208521e-16]]
[A] =
 [[1.50155575e+08 4.45004838e+07 0.00000000e+00]
 [4.44974703e+07 1.07288531e+08 0.00000000e+00]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 5.19662175e+07]]
[D] =
 [[60.771  7.663  4.019]
 [ 7.659 12.322  4.019]
 [ 4.019  4.019  9.567]]
```

**1st Attempt: Actual Output for First Iteration**

```
NM = 
[[2.57939977e+004]
 [7.26576487e+225]
 [2.35904846e+253]
 [7.25895469e+242]
 [1.18107381e+291]
 [1.61312569e+291]]
[A] =
 [[1.50155575e+08 4.45004838e+07 0.00000000e+00]
 [4.44974703e+07 1.07288531e+08 0.00000000e+00]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 5.19662175e+07]]
[D] =
 [[60.771  7.663  4.019]
 [ 7.659 12.322  4.019]
 [ 4.019  4.019  9.567]]
```

**2nd Try: First Iteration**

```
NM = [[2.18479897e+158]
 [3.03926820e+004]
 [1.62552246e+034]
 [1.00000121e+000]
 [1.07935186e+000]
 [2.60208521e-016]]
[A] =
 [[1.50155575e+08 4.45004838e+07 0.00000000e+00]
 [4.44974703e+07 1.07288531e+08 0.00000000e+00]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 5.19662175e+07]]
[D] =
 [[60.771  7.663  4.019]
 [ 7.659 12.322  4.019]
 [ 4.019  4.019  9.567]]
```

**3rd Try: First Iteration**

```
NM = [[ 2.57939977e+004]
 [ 3.03926820e+004]
 [-3.55271368e-013]
 [ 4.54183603e+225]
 [ 6.28847407e+094]
 [ 2.60208521e-016]]
[A] =
 [[1.50155575e+08 4.45004838e+07 0.00000000e+00]
 [4.44974703e+07 1.07288531e+08 0.00000000e+00]
 [0.00000000e+00 0.00000000e+00 5.19662175e+07]]
[D] =
 [[60.771  7.663  4.019]
 [ 7.659 12.322  4.019]
 [ 4.019  4.019  9.567]]
```

**4th Try: First Iteration**

```
NM = [[ 2.57939977e+04]
 [ 3.03926820e+04]
 [-3.55271368e-13]
 [ 1.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.00000000e+00]
 [ 2.60208521e-16]]
[A] =
 [[1.50155575e+008 4.45004838e+007 0.00000000e+000]
 [4.44974703e+007 1.07288531e+008 0.00000000e+000]
 [0.00000000e+000 0.00000000e+000 2.39203287e+198]]
[D] =
 [[60.771  7.663  4.019]
 [ 7.659 12.322  4.019]
 [ 4.019  4.019  9.567]]
```

As can be seen, the fourth iteration finally produced the correct NM matrix; however, the [A] matrix goes from having the correct values to an incorrect A[3][3] element. However, after a few more attempts at re-running the program, the program finally outputs all three correct matrices. As stated before, this can take anywhere between 1 and 15 attempts.

At this point, I'm lost with what could be causing these issues. I've given my code to others to run on their own computers and the program seems to have no issue. Any advice on how I can resolve this would be greatly appreciated. The full code and instructions for viewing the first iteration is below. If anything else is needed, please let me know.

**To Re-create**

1. Run the code making sure C.stress_critical_loads() is commented out and C.tsai_wu() is not commented out in the main method.
2. After running, scroll to the top of the output and then scroll down until the first instances of NM, [A], [B], and [D].
3. If you see an error message in the middle of the output code, it's because the NM matrix is wrong. The error message goes away when the NM matrix is correct. The program also runs despite the error message.

Thanks again for any advice anyone can give.

```
import numpy as np
import math
from tabulate import *


def stress_transformation_matrix(x):
    # This function calculates the stress transformation
    # matrix given an input value for the ply angle
    return np.array([
        [math.cos(x)**2, math.sin(x)**2, 2*math.sin(x)*math.cos(x)],
        [math.sin(x)**2, math.cos(x)**2, -2*math.sin(x)*math.cos(x)],
        [-math.sin(x)*math.cos(x), math.sin(x)*math.cos(x), math.cos(x)**2 - math.sin(x)**2]
    ])


def strain_transformation_matrix(x):
    # This function calculates the strain transformation
    # matrix given an input value for the ply angle
    return np.array([
        [math.cos(x)**2, math.sin(x)**2, math.sin(x)*math.cos(x)],
        [math.sin(x)**2, math.cos(x)**2, -math.sin(x)*math.cos(x)],
        [-2*math.sin(x)*math.cos(x), 2*math.sin(x)*math.cos(x), math.cos(x)**2-math.sin(x)**2]
    ])


def local_stiffness_matrix(E11, E22, G12, v12, v21):
    # This function calculates the local stiffness
    # given the material properties at each ply
    return np.array([
        [E11 / (1 - v12 * v21), v21 * E11 / (1 - v12 * v21), 0],
        [v12 * E22 / (1 - v12 * v21), E22 / (1 - v12 * v21), 0],
        [0, 0, G12]
    ])


class Properties:
    def __init__(self):
        # Material Properties
        self.M_E11 = np.array([181E9, 204E9, 138E9, 38.6E9, 76E9])
        self.M_E22 = np.array([10.3E9, 18.5E9, 9E9, 8.3E9, 5.5E9])
        self.M_G12 = np.array([7.17E9, 5.59E9, 7.1E9, 4.14E9, 2.3E9])
        self.M_v12 = np.array([0.280, 0.230, 0.300, 0.260, 0.340])
        self.M_v21 = np.array([0.016, 0.021, 0.019, 0.056, 0.33])
        self.E11 = np.array([])
        self.E22 = np.array([])
        self.G12 = np.array([])
        self.v12 = np.array([])
        self.v21 = np.array([])

        # Ultimate Failure Strengths
        self.P_SLT = np.array([1500E6, 1260E6, 1447E6, 1062E6, 1400E6])
        self.P_SLc = np.array([1500E6, 2499E6, 1447E6, 610E6, 235E6])
        self.P_STt = np.array([40E6, 61E6, 52E6, 31E6, 12E6])
        self.P_STc = np.array([246E6, 202E6, 206E6, 118E6, 53E6])
        self.P_SLTs = np.array([68E6, 67E6, 93E6, 72E6, 34E6])
        self.SLT = np.array([])
        self.SLc = np.array([])
        self.STt = np.array([])
        self.STc = np.array([])
        self.SLTs = np.array([])

        # Ultimate Failure Strains
        self.P_epsLtf = np.array([1.087E-2, 0, 1.380E-2, 2.807E-2, 0])
        self.P_epsLcf = np.array([0.652E-2, 0, 1.175E-2, 1.754E-2, 0])
        self.P_epsCtf = np.array([0.245E-2, 0, 0.436E-2, 0.456E-2, 0])
        self.P_epsCcf = np.array([1.818E-2, 0, 2E-2, 1.2E-2, 0])
        self.P_epsLTs = np.array([4E-2, 0, 2E-2, 4E-2, 0])
        self.epsLtf = np.array([])
        self.epsLcf = np.array([])
        self.epsCtf = np.array([])
        self.epsCcf = np.array([])
        self.epsLTs = np.array([])

        # Strength Ratios for stress and strain
        self.R11_s = np.array([])
        self.R22_s = np.array([])
        self.R12_s = np.array([])
        self.R11_e = np.array([])
        self.R22_e = np.array([])
        self.R12_e = np.array([])
        self.R_crit_s = np.array([])
        self.R_crit_e = np.array([])

        # Tsai-Wu Coefficients
        self.F11 = np.array([])
        self.F22 = np.array([])
        self.F12 = np.array([])
        self.F66 = np.array([])
        self.F1 = np.array([])
        self.F2 = np.array([])

        # Stiffness and Transformation Matrices
        self.Q = np.array([])
        self.Q_hat = np.array([])
        self.T = np.array([])
        self.T_hat = np.array([])

        # ABD Matrices
        self.A = np.empty(shape=(3, 3))
        self.B = np.empty(shape=(3, 3))
        self.D = np.empty(shape=(3, 3))
        self.ABD = np.empty(shape=(6, 6))

        # Laminate Loads
        self.Nxx = 200
        self.Nyy = 200
        self.Nxy = 0
        self.Mxx = 1
        self.Myy = 1
        self.Mxy = 0
        self.N_mech = np.array([])
        self.M_mech = np.array([])
        self.NT = np.empty(shape=(3, 1))
        self.MT = np.empty(shape=(3, 1))
        self.NM = np.array([])
        self.Nxx_cs = np.array([])
        self.Mxx_cs = np.array([])
        self.Nxx_ce = np.array([])
        self.Mxx_ce = np.array([])

        # Mid-plane Strains and Curvatures
        self.e0_k = np.array([])
        self.e0 = np.array([])
        self.k0 = np.array([])

        # Stresses and Strains
        self.sg = np.array([])      # global stress
        self.sl = np.array([])      # local stress
        self.eg = np.array([])      # global strain
        self.el = np.array([])      # local strain

        # Ply Orientations
        self.lam = None             # total laminate thickness
        self.z_lam = np.array([])   # laminate thickness from to pto bottom
        self.z_m = np.array([])     # mid-plane laminate thickness

        # Table and Material Properties
        self.mat = np.array([])
        self.mat_list = np.array([])

        # Total Ply Failure
        self.Beta = np.array([])

        # Angle at Each Ply (deg)
        self.angle = np.array([0, 0, 45, 45, -45, -45, 90, 90, -45, -45, 45, 45, 0, 0])
        self.a = np.array([])
        # Thickness at Each Ply (m)
        self.z = np.array([0.125E-3, 0.125E-3, 0.125E-3, 0.125E-3, 0.125E-3, 0.125E-3, 0.125E-3, 0.125E-3, 0.125E-3,
                           0.125E-3, 0.125E-3, 0.125E-3, 0.125E-3, 0.125E-3])
        # Number of Ply
        self.n = self.angle.size
        # Material at Each Ply
        self.m = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
        # 0: T300/5208
        # 1: B(4) 5505
        # 2: AS4/3501
        # 3: Scotchply 1002
        # 4: Kevlar49/Epoxy

        # Thermal Properties
        self.a1 = -0.018E-6     # longitudinal thermal expansion, deg. C
        self.a2 = 24.3E-6       # transverse thermal expansion, deg. C
        self.a3 = 0             # shear thermal expansion, deg. C
        self.dT = 100           # change in temperature, deg. C

    def ply_angle(self):
        a = np.array([])
        for i in range(self.n):
            a = np.append(a, math.radians(self.angle[i]))
        self.a = a

    def ply(self):
        # set total laminate ply failure array
        self.Beta = np.full(self.n, 1)

        # Determine the thickness of each ply
        self.lam = sum(self.z)
        print('Total Thickness =', self.lam)
        for i in range(self.n):
            self.z_lam = np.append(self.z_lam, -self.lam / 2 + (i + 1) * self.z[i])
        print('Top-Bottom =', self.z_lam)
        for i in range(self.n):
            self.z_m = np.append(self.z_m, -self.lam / 2 - self.z[i] / 2 + (i + 1) * self.z[i])
        print('Mid-plane =', self.z_m)

    def material(self):
        for i in range(self.n):
            m = self.m[i]
            # Material Properties
            self.E11 = np.append(self.E11, self.M_E11[m])
            self.E22 = np.append(self.E22, self.M_E22[m])
            self.G12 = np.append(self.G12, self.M_G12[m])
            self.v12 = np.append(self.v12, self.M_v12[m])
            self.v21 = np.append(self.v21, self.M_v21[m])
            self.mat_list = np.append(self.mat_list, m)
            # Ultimate Failure Strengths
            self.SLT = np.append(self.SLT, self.P_SLT[m])
            self.SLc = np.append(self.STc, self.P_SLc[m])
            self.STt = np.append(self.STt, self.P_STt[m])
            self.STc = np.append(self.STc, self.P_STc[m])
            self.SLTs = np.append(self.SLTs, self.P_SLTs[m])
            # Ultimate Failure Strains
            self.epsLtf = np.append(self.epsLtf, self.P_epsLtf[m])
            self.epsLcf = np.append(self.epsLcf, self.P_epsLcf[m])
            self.epsCtf = np.append(self.epsCtf, self.P_epsCtf[m])
            self.epsCcf = np.append(self.epsCcf, self.P_epsCcf[m])
            self.epsLTs = np.append(self.epsLTs, self.P_epsLTs[m])
            # Tsai-Wu Coefficients
            self.F11 = np.append(self.F11, 1 / (self.P_SLT[m] * self.P_SLc[m]))
            self.F22 = np.append(self.F22, 1 / (self.P_STt[m] * self.P_STc[m]))
            self.F12 = np.append(self.F12, -math.sqrt(self.F11[i] * self.F22[i]) / 2)
            self.F66 = np.append(self.F66, 1 / self.P_SLTs[m] ** 2)
            self.F1 = np.append(self.F1, 1 / self.P_SLT[m] - 1 / self.P_SLc[m])
            self.F2 = np.append(self.F2, 1 / self.P_STt[m] - 1 / self.P_STc[m])

            if m == 0: self.mat = np.append(self.mat, 'T300/5208')
            elif m == 1: self.mat = np.append(self.mat, 'B(4)/5505')
            elif m == 2: self.mat = np.append(self.mat, 'AS4/3501')
            elif m == 3: self.mat = np.append(self.mat, 'Scotchply 1002')
            else: self.mat = np.append(self.mat, 'Kevlar49/Epoxy')
        print('F11 = ', self.F11)
        print('F22 =', self.F22)
        print('F12 =', self.F12)
        print('F66 =', self.F66)
        print('F1 =', self.F1)
        print('F2 =', self.F2)

    def mechanical_loads(self):
        self.N_mech = np.array([
            [self.Nxx],
            [self.Nyy],
            [self.Nxy]
        ])
        self.M_mech = np.array([
            [self.Mxx],
            [self.Myy],
            [self.Mxy]
        ])

    def local_thermal_coef(self):
        al = np.array([
            [self.a1],
            [self.a2],
            [self.a3]
        ])
        return al

    def material_properties(self):
        # Creates a table for the material properties of each different ply
        mat_list = list(map(int, set(self.mat_list)))
        for i in mat_list:
            data = np.array([[self.E11[i], self.E22[i], self.G12[i], self.v12[i], self.v21[i]]])
            Q = local_stiffness_matrix(self.E11[i], self.E22[i], self.G12[i], self.v12[i], self.v21[i])
            print('\nMaterial =', self.mat[i], '(in SI units)')
            print(tabulate(data, headers=['E11', 'E22', 'G12', 'v12', 'v21']))
            print('\nMaterial =', self.mat[i], '(in Pa)')
            print('[Q] =\n', np.round(Q, 3))
            print('')

    def table(self):
        # Creates a table of ply number, thickness, orientation and material
        table = np.array([])
        for i in range(self.n):
            data = np.array([[i+1, self.mat[i], self.z[i], math.degrees(self.a[i])]])
            if i == 0:
                table = np.append(table, data)
            else:
                table = np.vstack([table, data])
        print(tabulate(table, headers=['Lamina', 'Material', 'Thickness', 'Orientation']))


class Calculations(Properties):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.NM = np.array([])          # Loads and Moments
        self.e0_k = np.array([])        # Mid-plane strains and curvatures
        self.fail_order = np.array([])  # Ply order of failure

    def a_matrix(self):
        for i in range(self.n):
            T = stress_transformation_matrix(self.a[i])
            T_hat = strain_transformation_matrix(self.a[i])
            if self.Beta[i] == 1:
                Q = local_stiffness_matrix(self.E11[i], self.E22[i], self.G12[i], self.v12[i], self.v21[i])
            else:
                Q = np.array([
                    [0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0]
                ])

            Q_hat = np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(T), Q)
            Q_hat = np.matmul(Q_hat, T_hat)
            A = Q_hat * (self.z_lam[i] - (self.z_lam[i] - self.z[i]))
            self.A = np.add(self.A, A)
            # print('\nLamina', i, '\t\u03B8 =', math.degrees(self.a[i]), 't =', self.z[i], 'Material =', self.mat[i-1])
            # print('[Q\u0302] =\n', np.round(Q_hat, 3))
        print('\nLaminate Stiffness Matrices\n[A] =\n', np.round(self.A, 3))

    def b_matrix(self):
        for i in range(self.n):
            T = stress_transformation_matrix(self.a[i])
            T_hat = strain_transformation_matrix(self.a[i])
            if self.Beta[i] == 1:
                Q = local_stiffness_matrix(self.E11[i], self.E22[i], self.G12[i], self.v12[i], self.v21[i])
            else:
                Q = np.array([
                    [0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0]
                ])

            Q_hat = np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(T), Q)
            Q_hat = np.matmul(Q_hat, T_hat)
            B = Q_hat * (self.z_lam[i] ** 2 - (self.z_lam[i] - self.z[i]) ** 2)
            self.B = np.add(self.B, B)
        self.B /= 2
        print('\n[B] =\n', np.round(self.B, 3))

    def d_matrix(self):
        for i in range(self.n):
            T = stress_transformation_matrix(self.a[i])
            T_hat = strain_transformation_matrix(self.a[i])
            if self.Beta[i] == 1:
                Q = local_stiffness_matrix(self.E11[i], self.E22[i], self.G12[i], self.v12[i], self.v21[i])
            else:
                Q = np.array([
                    [0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0]
                ])

            Q_hat = np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(T), Q)
            Q_hat = np.matmul(Q_hat, T_hat)
            D = Q_hat * (self.z_lam[i] ** 3 - (self.z_lam[i] - self.z[i]) ** 3)
            self.D = np.add(self.D, D)
        self.D /= 3
        print('\n[D] =\n', np.round(self.D, 3))

    def matrices_combined(self):
        self.a_matrix()     # call A matrix method
        self.b_matrix()     # call B matrix method
        self.d_matrix()     # call D matrix method

        self.ABD = np.array([
            [np.array(self.A[0][0]), np.array(self.A[0][1]), np.array(self.A[0][2]), np.array(self.B[0][0]), np.array(self.B[0][1]), np.array(self.B[0][2])],
            [np.array(self.A[1][0]), np.array(self.A[1][1]), np.array(self.A[1][2]), np.array(self.B[1][0]), np.array(self.B[1][1]), np.array(self.B[1][2])],
            [np.array(self.A[2][0]), np.array(self.A[2][1]), np.array(self.A[2][2]), np.array(self.B[2][0]), np.array(self.B[2][1]), np.array(self.B[2][2])],
            [np.array(self.B[0][0]), np.array(self.B[0][1]), np.array(self.B[0][2]), np.array(self.D[0][0]), np.array(self.D[0][1]), np.array(self.D[0][2])],
            [np.array(self.B[1][0]), np.array(self.B[1][1]), np.array(self.B[1][2]), np.array(self.D[1][0]), np.array(self.D[1][1]), np.array(self.D[1][2])],
            [np.array(self.B[2][0]), np.array(self.B[2][1]), np.array(self.B[2][2]), np.array(self.D[2][0]), np.array(self.D[2][1]), np.array(self.D[2][2])],
        ])

    def calculated_loads(self):
        self.NM = np.matmul(self.ABD, self.e0_k)
        print('\nResulting Loads and Moments\n', np.round(self.NM, 3))

    def thermal_loads(self):
        al = self.local_thermal_coef()
        for i in range(self.n):
            T = stress_transformation_matrix(self.a[i])
            T_hat = strain_transformation_matrix(self.a[i])
            if self.Beta[i] == 1:
                Q = local_stiffness_matrix(self.E11[i], self.E22[i], self.G12[i], self.v12[i], self.v21[i])
            else:
                Q = np.array([
                    [0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0],
                    [0, 0, 0]
                ])
            Q_hat = np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(T), Q)
            Q_hat = np.matmul(Q_hat, T_hat)
            ag = np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(T_hat), al)

            NT = np.matmul(Q_hat, ag) * (self.z_lam[i] - (self.z_lam[i] - self.z[i]))
            self.NT = np.add(self.NT, NT)
            MT = np.matmul(Q_hat, ag) * (self.z_lam[i] ** 2 - (self.z_lam[i] - self.z[i]) ** 2)
            self.MT = np.add(self.MT, MT)
        self.NT *= self.dT
        self.MT *= (self.dT / 2)

    def combined_loads(self):
        # Combine the mechanical and thermal loads
        self.mechanical_loads()
        self.thermal_loads()
        N = self.N_mech + self.NT
        M = self.M_mech + self.MT
        self.NM = np.vstack((N, M))
        print('\nNM =', self.NM)

    def calculated_midplane_strains_curvatures(self):
        self.matrices_combined()    # call ABD matrix method
        # self.loads()
        self.e0_k = np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(self.ABD), self.NM)
        # print('\nResulting Mid-Plane Strains and Curvatures\n', self.e0_k)
        self.e0 = np.array([
            self.e0_k[0],
            self.e0_k[1],
            self.e0_k[2]
        ])
        self.k0 = np.array([
            self.e0_k[3],
            self.e0_k[4],
            self.e0_k[5]
        ])

    def calculated_stresses_and_strains(self):
        self.combined_loads()  # call calculated loads method
        self.calculated_midplane_strains_curvatures()   # call mid-plane strains and curvature method
        for i in range(self.n):
            eg = np.array([self.e0 + self.z_m[i] * self.k0])
            if i == 0:
                self.eg = np.array(eg)
            else:
                self.eg = np.append(self.eg, eg, axis=0)
        for i in range(self.n):
            T_hat = strain_transformation_matrix(self.a[i])
            el = np.matrix(np.matmul(T_hat, self.eg[i]))
            if i == 0:
                self.el = np.array(el)
            else:
                self.el = np.append(self.el, el, axis=1)
        # All values of local strains are 1x3 arrays, so
        # each time the strain is needed, the specific
        # array must be selected and then transposed
        self.el = np.transpose(self.el)
        # print('[Local Strain] =', self.el)
        for i in range(self.n):
            Q = local_stiffness_matrix(self.E11[i], self.E22[i], self.G12[i], self.v12[i], self.v21[i])
            sl = np.matrix(np.matmul(Q, np.transpose(np.matrix(self.el[i]))))
            if i == 0:
                self.sl = np.array(sl)
            else:
                self.sl = np.append(self.sl, sl, axis=1)
        # All values of local stress are 1x3 arrays, so
        # each time the stress is needed, the specific
        # array must be selected and then transposed
        self.sl = np.transpose(self.sl)
        print('\n[Local Stress] =\n', self.sl)

    def stress_strength_ratio_11(self):
        for i in range(self.n):
            sl = np.transpose(self.sl[i])
            if float(sl[0]) >= 0:
                self.R11_s = np.append(self.R11_s, self.SLT[i] / float(sl[0]))
            else:
                self.R11_s = np.append(self.R11_s, self.SLc[i] / abs(float(sl[0])))

    def stress_strength_ratio_22(self):
        for i in range(self.n):
            sl = np.transpose(self.sl[i])
            if float(sl[1]) >= 0:
                self.R22_s = np.append(self.R22_s, self.STt[i] / float(sl[1]))
            else:
                self.R22_s = np.append(self.R22_s, self.STc[i] / abs(float(sl[1])))

    def stress_strength_ratio_12(self):
        for i in range(self.n):
            sl = np.transpose(self.sl[i])
            self.R12_s = np.append(self.R12_s, self.SLTs[i] / abs(float(sl[2])))

    def stress_critical_loads(self):
        self.calculated_stresses_and_strains()
        self.stress_strength_ratio_11()     # call R11 method
        self.stress_strength_ratio_22()     # call R22 method
        self.stress_strength_ratio_12()     # call R12 method
        for i in range(self.n):
            R = np.array([
                [self.R11_s[i], self.R22_s[i], self.R12_s[i]]
            ])
            if self.Beta[i] == 1:
                R_crit = np.min(R)
            else:
                R_crit = 9999
            self.R_crit_s = np.append(self.R_crit_s, R_crit)
            self.Nxx_cs = np.append(self.Nxx_cs, R_crit * self.Nxx)
            self.Mxx_cs = np.append(self.Mxx_cs, R_crit * self.Mxx)
        Nxx_c = np.min(self.Nxx_cs)
        N_pos = np.where(self.Nxx_cs == Nxx_c)[0]
        Mxx_c = np.min(self.Mxx_cs)
        self.fail_order = np.append(self.fail_order, N_pos + 1)
        print('\nPly Failure in ply', N_pos + 1)
        print('R_crit =', np.min(self.R_crit_s))
        print('Critical in-plane loading at ply', N_pos + 1, '=', Nxx_c, '')
        print('Critical bending loading at ply', N_pos + 1, '=', Mxx_c, '')
        print('Stress: Nxx_c =', Nxx_c)
        print('Stress: Mxx_c =', Mxx_c)

        Beta = np.full(self.n, 0)
        if not np.array_equal(self.Beta, Beta):
            self.Beta[N_pos] = 0
            print(self.Beta)
            # Reset all values
            self.A = np.zeros(shape=(3, 3))
            self.B = np.zeros(shape=(3, 3))
            self.D = np.zeros(shape=(3, 3))
            self.ABD = np.zeros(shape=(6, 6))
            self.eg = np.zeros([])
            self.el = np.zeros([])
            self.sl = np.zeros([])
            self.NT = np.zeros(shape=(3, 1))
            self.MT = np.zeros(shape=(3, 1))
            self.NM = np.zeros(shape=(6, 1))
            self.R11_s = np.zeros([])
            self.R22_s = np.zeros([])
            self.R12_s = np.zeros([])
            self.R_crit_s = np.zeros([])
            self.Nxx_cs = np.zeros([])
            self.Mxx_cs = np.zeros([])
            # re-run calculations
            if not np.array_equal(self.Beta, Beta):
                self.stress_critical_loads()
            else:
                print('Ply Fail Order =', self.fail_order)

    def tsai_wu(self):
        self.calculated_stresses_and_strains()
        a = np.array([])
        b = np.array([])
        c = np.array([])
        R1 = np.array([])
        R2 = np.array([])
        for i in range(self.n):
            sl = np.transpose(self.sl[i])
            a = np.append(a, self.F11[i] * sl[0] ** 2 + 2 * self.F12[i] * sl[0] * sl[1]
                          + self.F22[i] * sl[1] ** 2 + self.F66[i] * sl[2] ** 2)
            b = np.append(b, self.F1[i] * sl[0] + self.F2[i] * sl[1])
            c = np.append(c, -1)
        for i in range(self.n):
            if self.Beta[i] == 1:
                R1 = np.append(R1, (-b[i] + math.sqrt(b[i]**2 - 4 * a[i] * c[i])) / (2 * a[i]))
                R2 = np.append(R2, (-b[i] - math.sqrt(b[i]**2 - 4 * a[i] * c[i])) / (2 * a[i]))
            else:
                R1 = np.append(R1, 9999)
                R2 = np.append(R2, -9999)
        R_crit = np.min(R1)
        R_crit_pos = np.where(R1 == R_crit)[0]
        # print('R1 =', R1)
        # print('R2 =', R2)
        print('\nR_cr at ply', R_crit_pos + 1, '=', R_crit, '')
        self.fail_order = np.append(self.fail_order, R_crit_pos + 1)

        NTW_xxc = R_crit * self.Nxx
        MTW_xxc = R_crit * self.Mxx
        print('N_xx,cr for ply', R_crit_pos + 1, '=', NTW_xxc)
        print('M_xx,cr for ply', R_crit_pos + 1, '=', MTW_xxc)

        Beta = np.full(self.n, 0)
        if not np.array_equal(self.Beta, Beta):
            self.Beta[R_crit_pos] = 0
            print('\nFailure Progression =', self.Beta)
            # Reset all values
            self.A = np.zeros(shape=(3, 3))
            self.B = np.zeros(shape=(3, 3))
            self.D = np.zeros(shape=(3, 3))
            self.ABD = np.zeros(shape=(6, 6))
            self.eg = np.zeros([])
            self.el = np.zeros([])
            self.sl = np.zeros([])
            self.NT = np.zeros(shape=(3, 1))
            self.MT = np.zeros(shape=(3, 1))
            self.NM = np.zeros(shape=(6, 1))
            # re-run all values
            if not np.array_equal(self.Beta, Beta):
                self.tsai_wu()
            else:
                print('Ply Fail Order =', self.fail_order)


def main():

    C = Calculations()
    C.ply_angle()
    C.ply()
    C.material()
    C.material_properties()
    C.table()
    # Comment out for Tsai-Wu failure calculations
    # print('\nCritical Stress Criterion')
    # C.stress_critical_loads()
    # Comment out for Maximum Stress failure calculations
    print('\nTsai-Wu Criterion\n')
    C.tsai_wu()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's the cause of your problem, but your code has six calls to `np.empty`.  I don't see any later initialization of these arrays.

`np.empty` causes the array to not be initialized, and the memory will contain random garbage.  Try replace those with `np.zeros` and see if you get better results.

Comment: I think you just fixed it. I've run the program multiple times now and it's outputting the same results, and they are correct! Who knew changing np.empty to np.zeros would fix months worth of coding struggles. Thank you so much!